# Cannot Get / Post

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, server

I am trying to link the server-side with the html but whenever I do the node server.js and open the html nothing works. I also tried going into http://localhost:3000/post but then the only thing I get is Cannot Get / Post.

```js
var playerPoint1 = 0;
var playerPoint2 = 0;
var computerPoint = 0;
var gameEnd = false;
var url = "http://localhost:3000/post";

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#container").load("playerNumber.txt");
  });
});

function playerNumberSelection(n) {
  if (n == 1) {
    $("#container").load("singlePlayer.txt");
  } else {
    $("#container").load("multiPlayer.txt")
  }
}

function multiPlayerGame() {
  $("#container").load("multiPlayerGame.txt");
  var firstName = document.getElementById("firstPlayerName").value;
  var secondName = document.getElementById("secondPlayerName").value;
  var playerOne;
  var playerTwo;
  var onePressed = false;
  var twoPressed = false;
  window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    keyPressed = event.key;
    if (!onePressed) {
      if (keyPressed == 'a' || keyPressed == 's' || keyPressed == 'd') {
        playerOne = keyPressed;
        console.log(playerOne);
        onePressed = true;
      }
    } else if (!twoPressed) {
      if (keyPressed == 'j' || keyPressed == 'k' || keyPressed == 'l') {
        playerTwo = keyPressed;
        console.log(playerTwo);
        twoPressed = true;
      }
    }
    if (onePressed && twoPressed) {
      console.log("yes")
      if (playerOne == 'a' && playerTwo == 'j' || playerOne == 's' && playerTwo == 'k' || playerOne == 'd' && playerTwo == 'l') {
        alert("TIE");
      } else if (playerOne == 'a' && playerTwo == 'l' || playerOne == 's' && playerTwo == 'j' || playerOne == 'd' && playerTwo == 'k') {
        alert(firstName + " WINS");
        playerPoint1++;
        $("#playerPoint1").html(playerPoint1);
      } else {
        alert(secondName + " WINS");
        playerPoint2++;
        $("#playerPoint2").html(playerPoint2);
      }
      onePressed = false;
      twoPressed = false;
    }
  });
}

function singlePlayer(choice) {
  $.post(
    url + '?data=' + JSON.stringify({
      'action': 'singlePlayer',
      'player_Choice': choice,
    }),
    response
  );
}

function response(data, status) {
  var response = JSON.parse(data);
  //if singlePlayer recieved
  if (response['action'] == 'singlePlayer') {
    computerPoint = response['computerPoint'];
    playerPoint1 = response['playerPoint1'];
    //display the result for each points
    $("#playerPoint").html(playerPoint1);
    $("#computerPoint").html(computer);
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <nav>
    <img src="" id="logo" class="logo">
  </nav>
  <h1>WELCOME</h1>
  <div class="buttonContainer">
    <button>START</button>
  </div>
  <footer>

  </footer>
</div>
```

server side js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var playerPoint1 = 0;
var playerPoint2 = 0;
var computer = 0;

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.post('/post', (req, res) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    console.log("New express client");
    console.log("Received: ");
    console.log(JSON.parse(req.query['data']));
    var z = JSON.parse(req.query['data']);

    // check if the request action is singlePlayer
    if (z['action']=='singlePlayer') {
        var player_Choice = z['player_Choice'];
        singlePlayer(player_Choice);
        var jsontext = JSON.stringify({
            'computerPoint': computer,
            'playerPoint1': playerPoint1
        });
        console.log(jsontext);
        console.log(codes);
    } else {
        res.send(JSON.stringify({ 'msg': 'error!!!' }));
    }
}).listen(3000);
console.log("Server is running!");

function singlePlayer(player_Choice){
    var comp = randomGenerator();
        if(player_Choice==comp){
            console.log("TIE");
        }else if(player_Choice==1&&comp==2||player_Choice==2&&comp==3||player_Choice==3&&comp==1){
            alert("LOSE");
            computer++;
        }else{
            alert("WIN");
            playerPoint1++;
          }
}

function randomGenerator(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*3 + 1);
}
```

The game is Rock Paper Scissor I only tried the single-player part since I cant even get it to run. Help Please

Comment: please try to get your code to a [mcve]

Comment: i believe you should use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors
instead of res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

Comment: What is the error you get in your jQuery AJAX? (post)

Comment: What's in multiPlayerGame.txt ?

Comment: Consider using [`body-parser`](https://npmjs.com/package/body-parser).

Comment: @code - That's built into Express not. There's no point in using an external module.

Comment: @Quentin It would make processing form data a lot easier.

Comment: @code - No, it wouldn't. It has no features that the built-in body parsers lack. What's more, the code in the question is dumping the JSON into the query string, not the body, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect this to work? There are so many issues with all parts of the code.

That is not how you make a request to an API. I suggest learning about `fetch`, `await`/`async`, and providing data in the body of a POST request.

Do not use the keyword `var` when defining variables - instead use `const` or `let` (https://hackernoon.com/why-you-shouldnt-use-var-anymore-f109a58b9b70)

Comment: Honestly I have no idea. My professor gave us a lab in a similar way as to what I did and his worked on a local host. The program does not when when I try to run it using the node js. The server is running but wont connect itself with the html part.

Comment: I want it to connect with the html first and then go ahead with the other issues if thats possible